# Map fileds in multiple csv files and combine the rows

Tags: csv, awk

The data in my first csv file is:

```
ID, name, city
1, John, NYC
2
3
4, Sam, SFO
5
```

In second csv file

```
ID, name, city
3, Tim, STL
2, Daniel, BOS
```

Third csv file

```
ID, name, city
5, Eric, AST
```

I want a single csv file with the aggregated data:

```
ID, name, city
1, John, NYC
2, Daniel, BOS
3, Tim, STL
4, Sam, SFO
5, Eric, AST
```

I'm trying to do this with awk but I'm a beginner so I couldn't figure out a way to do this. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: You must use awk? Why not using the join command?

Answer (score 0):

In the output we suppress no-name records and headers, then sort by ID:

```
$ (head -1 1st.csv
   awk -F, 'NF > 2 && FNR > 1' {1st,2nd,3rd}.csv | sort -n ) | tee combined.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data in the CSVs are same as the ones you shared above.

```
cat f1.csv f2.csv f3.csv|awk -F',' '$2!="" && $3!=""'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following in single awk and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{print;next}FNR>1{a[$1]=NF>1 && a[$1]?a[$1] FS $0:(NF>1?$0:"")} END{for(i in a){if(a[i]){print a[i] | "sort"}}}' 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv
```

Output will be as follows.

```
ID, name, city
 1, John, NYC
 2, Daniel, BOS
 3, Tim, STL
 4, Sam, SFO
 5, Eric, AST
```

It should be working for more than 3 files too, only thing if it crosses limit of open files then in order to avoid any `too many files opened` error, we have to run following code.

```
awk -F, '
NR==1{
  print;
  next
}
FNR==1{
  if(val){
    close(val)
};
  val=FILENAME
}
FNR>1{
  a[$1]=NF>1 && a[$1]?a[$1] FS $0:(NF>1?$0:"")
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    if(a[i]){
     print a[i] | "sort"
}}
}
' 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv
```

Comment: There is no need of `if(val){ close(val) } val=FILENAME`, `too many files opened error` will not come here, awk reads file one by one, and file handler will be closed meanwhile.

Comment: not sure who is giving me down votes and without telling me a reason, it discourages a person :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat f1
ID, name, city
1, John, NYC
2
3
4, Sam, SFO
5 

$ cat f2
ID, name, city
3, Tim, STL
2, Daniel, BOS

$ cat f3
ID, name, city
5, Eric, AST

$ awk -F, 'FNR==1{i++}i<3{a[$1+0]=$0;next}i==3 && $1+0 in a{print a[$1+0];next}1' f2 f3 f1
ID, name, city
1, John, NYC
2, Daniel, BOS
3, Tim, STL
4, Sam, SFO
5, Eric, AST
```